# Why python's subprocess.PIPE is not blocking?

Tags: python, select, subprocess, pipe, blocking

Consider the below code:

```
import os, select, subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["pwd"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
r, _, _ = select.select([p1.stdout.fileno()], [], [])
os.read(r[0], 1024)
r, _, _ = select.select([p1.stdout.fileno()], [], [])
os.read(r[0], 1024)
```

The `select` function properly reports that the `p1.stdout` pipe has data in it but the second time while it reports the same, this pipe has no data. Everyone's problem is that the subprocess pipes are blocking. My problem is that this pipe is not blocking. I want the select function to block until the pipe has data in it.

Here is the output:

```
>>> import os, select, subprocess
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["pwd"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
>>> r, _, _ = select.select([p1.stdout.fileno()], [], [])
>>> os.read(r[0], 1024)
b'/tmp\n'
>>> r, _, _ = select.select([p1.stdout.fileno()], [], [])
>>> os.read(r[0], 1024)
b''
>>>
```

Comment: The subprocess has exited, so the pipe is closed.

Comment: Then why I am not getting an exception while trying to read from it? Also with ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd I see that the pipe is still there: `3 -> 'pipe:[2892611]'`. How can I do a blocking read on this pipe while is still open?

Comment: You don't get an exception when you try to read at the end of a stream. It just returns an empty string.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects): **If the end of the file has been reached, `f.read()` will return an empty string**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subprocess has exited, so the write end of the pipe is closed. When you try to read from the pipe again, you're at EOF, so an empty string is returned.

The documentation of [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) explains this:

> If the end of the file has been reached, `f.read()` will return an empty string

`select()` only blocks if trying to read would have blocked. You don't block when you're at EOF, it returns the empty string immediately.